# Why are URLs encoded in Base32?

Tags: url, uri, radix, base32

This is a really short question I think but I'm not sure I understand the point of it.

Why are URLs encoded in Base32? What are the benefits of it and what are the drawbacks of it?

Comment: I reworded your question - I hope that's what you meant by 'URL ids'?

Comment: Yes. Although for example tinyurl only does its ids I believe not sure thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes URL data needs to be encoded to encapsulate things that aren't easily type-able, such as "ÓĆ", or even binary data that has no text representation at all. Putting that inside of a query string was problematic. Some servers don't understand Unicode text in a query string, though that situation is certainly getting better.

So the data needs to be encoded somehow that the server can interpret correctly, and the application knows how to use. Base32 is commonly used for that. It encodes any binary data into a ASCII text representation of that data. When the original data is needed, it is decoded.

So why not base64? Base64 will almost always have a shorter encoding length. Base64's weakness is that it uses both upper and lower case letter for encoding. There is a distinction between `A` and `a`. Whereas Base32 only uses one letter's casing, so it can be case insensitive. Generally (but not always), URLs are case insensitive, and using Base32 keeps that notion alive. This distinction is useful when the encoded data is meant to be typed, read aloud, etc.

The drawback to Base32 is that the resulting encoding is almost always longer due to a much smaller character set.

Comment: Seems logical to me. Does youtube use this method for their video links? if so how do they keep the fixed length of the string id?